# Drupal 7- creating block view and page view

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

How to create a single view, which will show the list of articles in (block  view) and the list of basic page in (page view) in drupal 7?

Comment: Hi. There are a ton of tutorials about using Views module. Here's one that might help. [Beginner Tutorial to Views for Drupal 7](https://dev.acquia.com/blog/a-totally-beginner-tutorial-to-views-for-drupal-7/22/01/2016/9576) . Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a page view and a block view.
2. Place the block view in any region as you see fit.
3. Configure the newly created block in Structure->Blocks
4. Select 'only on listed pages' and paste the path of the page view
5. Save configuration and load the page